# Portrait vs. landscape format of Civireport

Tags: civireport

I'm a bit baffled by this - all of our civireports are coming out in Landscape format when printed to PDF, even though the Print Page (PDF) Formats setting is Portrait. I tried this with wkhtmltopdf and the default internal PDF generator, but there's no change. All suggestions welcome. This is Civi 5.38.0 on Wordpress 5.7.2.